# How to use js map correclty below code is throwing error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

not sure if i am missing anything below code is throwing error map is not a function any idea ?

any better approach right this code to achieve results ?

main.js

```
const errorCodes = [99,890];
    const drug = [{
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Lipitor",
        "specialtyPrice": {}
      },
      {
        "isBrand": false,
        "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
        "drugStrength": "80mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
          "totalQuantity": 90,
          "rejectMessage": [{
            "settlementCode": "99",
            "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
          }]
        },
        "retailPrice": {
          "totalQuantity": 30,
          "rejectMessage": [{
            "settlementCode": "99",
            "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
          }]
        },
        "specialtyPrice": {}
      }
    ];

          const filteredPrices = drug.map(item => {
            const errorCodes = drugPriceErrors;
            const pricePath = ['mailPrice.rejectMessage', 'retailPrice.rejectMessage'];

            _.forEach(pricePath, function (path)  {
              const rejectMsg = _.get(item, path);
              const hasCode = rejectMsg && rejectMsg.find(i => !!~errorCodes.indexOf(+i.settlementCode));
              hasCode && delete item[path.split('.').shift()];
            });

            return item;
          });
```

Error :

```
TypeError: drug.map is not a function
```

Comment: Verify what `drug` is. It must not be an array.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with that data. What is `typeof(drug)`?

Comment: its an array object

Comment: Did you test it right before attempting to use `map`, or are you just inferring that it should be an array?

Comment: it should return an array i haven't tested got stuck here